# how can I redirect first timers on the website to the signup page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so basicly here is my script:

```
window.onload = () => {
    `enter code here`   if (**first_time**) {
           window.location.href = "www.netlify.app/teamadventures.signup";
       }
   }
```

I want to make it so that if it's your first time on the website you get taken to a signup page automatically. How do I do this with vanilla JS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `cookies` or `localStorage` for that. The `localStorage` is the easiest method. First check if there is something stored on it with `getItem`. If not, store this information (the user visited the page) in `localStorage` with `setItem` and redirect the page to the Sign Up.

```js
var first_time = localStorage.getItem("first_time");

if (!first_time){
localStorage.setItem("first_time", 1);
window.location.href = "www.netlify.app/teamadventures.signup";
}
```

Comment: But where do i put the onLoad and login code?

Comment: Please provide an explanation. The OP probably doesn't even know what `localStorage` is.

Comment: @xgamerts You can place this piece of code anywhere in the script (inside or outside the onload) since this piece of code does not require the page to be loaded in order to work.

Comment: If I may ask… why should JS look at localStorage for a user that’s not even loggedin?

Comment: But where do I put the location.herf

Comment: @xgamerts refresh the page to see the updated answer.